# How to get which element I have clicked on? | React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I render 12 cards on the screen each of which have a unique key attribute.

I only started learning react and I want function to only to be called when a card has been clicked and save only that key which been clicked in state if an other has been clicked then update the state and then have 2 ids there and not all 12.

This is my Card component (the others are irrelevant I think)

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {CardData} from "./Data/CardsData.js" 
import style from "../style/Cards.css"
import Score from "./Score.js";

const Cards = () =>{
    const [bestScore, setBestScore] = useState(0);
    const [scoreRN, setScoreRN] = useState(0);
    const [clickedCard, setClickedCard] =useState([]);
    
    const CardClick = () =>{
        for(let card of CardData)
        setClickedCard( clickedCard.concat(card))
        console.log(clickedCard)
        }
    return(
         <div id="content">
            <Score bestScore={bestScore} scoreRN={scoreRN}/>
            {CardData.map((data) => {
                return(
                    <div key={data.id} className="card" onClick={CardClick}>
                        <img src={data.img}></img>
                        <h2>{data.name}</h2>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Cards;
```

This way I only get the last card's id into my clickedCard array, every time I click on a card.

I have also could do it where I added every cardid on every click.

And an additional thing that I don't fully understand: Why is it that now the 1. console log is returns an empty array (then 1, 2,3 ... elemement)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the for loop if you just want to add the clicked card into the array, but you do need to pass a `card` parameter so that the callback knows which card was clicked:

```
    const CardClick = (card) =>{
        // for(let card of CardData) - you can remove this line
        setClickedCard( clickedCard.concat(card))
        console.log(clickedCard)
        }
```

In your JSX:

```
                    <div key={data.id} className="card" onClick={() => CardClick(data)}>
                        <img src={data.img}></img>
                        <h2>{data.name}</h2>
                    </div>
```

Also, your `console.log` is returning an empty array because react state changes aren't immediate, so even after you called `setClickedCard`, `clickedCard` will still be its old value in the same function until React's next render.

Comment: damn I totally forgot about the parameters between these much props and this and whatever  I got it now thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

`CardClick` callback is a `MouseEventHandler` so it receives `event` as first argument.

You can then get `event.currentTarget.id` in the `CardClick` function (if your element has an `id`)

Another way is to explicit pass data to the `onClick` handler like `onClick={event => CardClick(event, data.id)}`. Then your `CardClick` function can accept your aditionnal arguments